# Independent number of K_4-free graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be an edge-disjoint triangle graphs, i.e, any two distinct triangles in $G$ have not a common edge. How much could the independent number of $G$ be small? Is it possible $\alpha(G)=o(|G|)$?

Answer (score 0):

If no two triangles share an edge, then $G$ is $K_4$ free. The [Ramsey Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html) $R(4,t)$ tells you how large $G$ can be without having a $K_4$ or an $N_t$. In particular, there exist constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that

$$   c_{1} \frac{ t^{5/2}}{\ln ^2 t}<R(4,t)< c_{2} \frac{ t^{3}}{\ln ^2 t} $$

So, given $|G|=n$ the independence number must be at least $\approx n^{1/3}$

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I think you should use here $R(4,t)$!!  Also, this bound can be achieved by a simpler argument.!! Since we have  $$\alpha(G)\geq \frac{n}{\Delta+1}, \alpha(G)\geq \frac{\Delta}{3}$$

Comment: @MathFun If no two triangles share an edge then $G$ is not only $K_4$-free, it is $K_4-e$-free, so the question seems to be about the generalized Ramsey number $R(K_4-e,K_t).$ I don't know anything about such things, but I guess it's a lot smaller than $R(4,t)?$

Comment: Yes! that's correct as you can see my argument in above also confirm your statment!!

Comment: @MathFun I forgot to give you credit. Sorry about that! Thanks again. Your answer is much simpler.

Comment: @mm8511 Thanks for your time and your solution too. I really appreciate it

Comment: @bof  The Independence number (in terms of the order of the graph $n$) is bounded below by the triangle free Ramsey number ($R(3,t)$), so in general you still have a $\sqrt{n \cdot} \log n$ lower bound on $\alpha (G)$ for this class of graphs.